# php codeigniter websites showing not connected to server in safari ios phone

Tags: php, ios, codeigniter, cookies, safari

i have a live website made n codeigniter

below is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

the website is working fine android, desktops and laptops. but I got complaints from few users using iPhone, when they open in safari they are getting the following error:

> safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server

can anyone please tell me what could be the issue here and how I can solve it. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a code perspective the page seems to load fine in Safari iPhone but it does take some time and could potentially time out for some users.

If you take a look at Google's PageSpeed Insights, you can see the website loads slower on mobile [image]

Comment: I understand the loading problem bro, but some users in ios is not even getting the page, safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server error is coming.. Is it any session or cookie issue in codeigniter